# How can I configure JUnit to ignore @Before annotation only in a Test method

Tags: java, junit

I would like know, how can I make a JUnit ignore @Before only in oone method Test.

I found how to ignore in a Class, but I need only in one Test.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the question because it will resolve your problem ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `@Rule` for that. Here is an example:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Rule
    public TestName testName = new TestName();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        if (testName.getMethodName().equals("someTest")) {
            // your logic for the `someTest` method
        } else {
            // logic for the rest of the tests
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        //
    }

    @Test
    public void anotherTest() {
        //
    }

    @Test
    public void yetAnotherTest() {
        //
    }
}
```

However, how @mslowiak pointed already, this is not a good idea. The JUnit core concept is test isolation. So, if you need different init steps for the different tests you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: In @Before I configure to make  login with User1 but only in one test I need make login with User2. Do you have any idea how to make this?

Comment: There are so many solutions for that. The first thing that comes to mind is to use parameterized tests, where your user would be injected into your test method from data provider.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `@Before` annotation is to have consistent behavior in every test.
In your case extracting before logic to a method and call it with each required test would be a better idea.